# Add values in same line in C programming

Tags: c, eclipse, development-environment

I want to print multiple values on same line and then go to next line and print the same values and goes to next line and so on.
for ex:-

```
3 5 10
2 7 15
```

in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a,b,n,i,j,l;

   printf("Enter total digit in a line:");

   scanf("%d",&n);

   printf("Enter number of lines:");

   scanf("%d",&l);

   for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
   {
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
      {
         printf("enter values for line :");
         scanf("%d",&n);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: for ex:-                                                              3 5 10                                                                 2 7 15...... 3 5 10 are in one line and 2 7 15 are in different line

Comment: Are you serious with that vertical spacing?

Comment: take a counter and increment it in the inner loop if counter ==3 
break the line else increment the counter 
and inialize it in the outter for loop

Comment: Your question is not clear at all ... do you want the user to input M x N numbers and then print them in a rectangle that's M x N?

Comment: You should replace "Enter total digit in a line:" by "Enter total numbers in a line:"

Answer (score 2):

For each line, read input as string with e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then use e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) in a loop to extract each number and use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the numbers to integer values, and add them up.

---

The above solution contains of four parts, so lets split it up and do one at a time.

1. For each line, read input with [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

   This is pretty simple, as all you have to do is use your outer loop and ask the user to enter numbers there, as well as read the input there as well:

   ```
   for (i = 1; i <= l; i++)
   {
       printf("Enter numbers for line number %d: ", i);

       char input[128];
       fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
   }
   ```
2. Use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) in a loop to extract each number from the input.

   ```
   for (i = 1; i <= l; i++)
   {
       /* The code to read the input... */

       char *pointer = strtok(input, " ");
       while (pointer != NULL)
       {
           /* `pointer` is now pointing to the next space-delimited number */

           /* Find the next space-delimited number */
           pointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the numbers to integer values.

   ```
   {
       /* `pointer` is now pointing to the next space-delimited number */
       /* Convert string to number */
       long value = strtol(pointer, NULL, 10);

       /* Find the next space-delimited number... */
   }
   ```
4. Finally add all values in the line.

   ```
   for (i = 1; i <= l; i++)
   {
       long sum = 0;

       /* ... */

       {
           long value = strtol(pointer, NULL, 10);
           sum += value;
       }

       printf("The sum of all values on line %d is %ld\n", i, sum);
   }
   ```

Putting it all together, we get this code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= l; i++)
{
    printf("Enter numbers for line number %d: ", i);

    char input[128];
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    long sum = 0;

    char *pointer = strtok(input, " ");
    while (pointer != NULL)
    {
        /* `pointer` is now pointing to the next space-delimited number */
        /* Convert string to number */
        long value = strtol(pointer, NULL, 10);
        sum += value;

        /* Find the next space-delimited number */
        pointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("The sum of all values on line %d is %ld\n", i, sum);
}
```

**Note:** The above code have no error checking. I leave that as an exercise to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n, l, i, j;

    printf("Enter total digit in a line:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter number of lines:");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
        long sum =0;
        printf("enter values for line : ");
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            int num;
            scanf("%d", &num);//n : Names are colliding
            sum += num;
        }
        printf("sum of line : %ld\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```